# I want to to join client's sqlite3 db table with server's mysql db

Tags: mysql, join, sqlite, sql-order-by

```
client's db   (ios sqlite3)

id     pressed
 1        1
 2        1
 3        1
 4        0
 5        0


 server's db (mysql)

id       title
 1        a
 2        b
 3        c
 4        d
 5        e
```

I want to apply to server's db ordered by pressed asc result in client's db.

so wanted reseult is d,e,a,b,c. but problem is one is client, another is server.

and one is sqlite3 another is mysql.

how I get that result?

Comment: Since the data are in two completely separate locations, I imagine you'll have to query them separately and combine the data programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's MSWindows, then you can just set up odbc data sources for both tables and create a query in MSAccess. I don't think this can be done using other tools without some code in the middle.